# get method in wordpress form

Tags: forms, methods, get, using

I want to submit form in wordpress using get method but when I submitted it is show 404 not found page.

I googled but not found.

anyone can he me?

```
<form action="" method="get">
    <label>ID</label>
    <input type="text" name="id">
    <lable>Name</lable>
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="submit" value="Go!">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this ...

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_form_method

Your form action doesn't have anything in it - this chunk of code

```
<form action="" method="get">
```

It should look more like this

```
<form action="page.html" method="get">
```

That page will need to do something with the data you've just sent it ...

If you're trying to have a simple form on your site and don't really know much about it you might be better off with a plugin

Try something like 'contact form7' ... very popular